# Vala: reducing the size of dependencies

Tags: vala

I am developing small command line utilities using Vala on win32. Programs compiled using vala depend on the following DLLs

- libgobject-2.0-0.dll
- libgthread-2.0-0.dll
- libglib-2.0-0.dll

They are taking up 1500 kbyes of space. Is there a way to reduce the size of these dependencies (besides compressing them with UPX and the like)? I can't imagine a simple helloworld like app using all the features provided by glib.

**Thanks!**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If your vala source is fairly simple, you may be able to compile it in the posix profile

```
valac --profile posix hello.vala
```

Then your binary will not have any dependency outside of the standard C library. However, the posix profile may still be experimental.

Comment: Profiles have been dropped, so now it's more a matter of `--nostdpkg`.