# Compiling a Vala source On Windows

Tags: windows, vala

I compiled a vala program by using following command:

```
valac test.vala
```

Of course am I able to run the program on my computer, but when I am trying to run the .exe file on a different one I get following error:

```
libglib-***.dll is missing on this computer
```

This is how my source code looks like:

```
using GLib;
int main(string[] args)
{
    bool running = true;
    while(running)
    {
        print("Hello World\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The error is pretty clear, but what can I do against it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Along your exe file you will need to install all the libraries you use (glib, gio, etc ...) and their own dependencies (Gtk will require gdk,cairo,pango, and some more).

Edit: take a look at this [question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5332402/vala-reducing-the-size-of-dependencies), the minimal dependencies are listed.