# compiled vala itself with vala on windows

Tags: vala

I'm not sure if this question is correct but...

Ok, is possible compiled the source vala in vala

because I bean downloading vala source code and inside has many vala files

here vala release source code
https://wiki.gnome.org/Vala/Release

I have been installed on windows this version

https://code.google.com/p/vala-win32/downloads/list

vala-0.12.0.exe

I wont compile the last vala release whit the vala on windows

oky, gracias :D

please, not confused with this question,
[Compiling a Vala source On Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12324397/compiling-a-vala-source-on-windows)

Comment: Your question is a little bit unclear...you want to compile vala from source in a windows environment??

Comment: not, I wont compile source vala whit vala I download from this https://wiki.gnome.org/Vala/Release

Comment: Did you follow this wiki instructions: http://linbox.free.fr/vala/

Comment: ok, but it is used mingw and make, and I expect something like '> valac sourceCodeVala.vala'

Answer (score 6):

If 0.20.1 is enough, you can use http://www.tarnyko.net/en/?q=node/35 and possibly avoid this whole thing.

If you *really* need 0.22.0, Vala release tarballs don't actually require valac to compile—they contain all the generated C.  You should be able to use the build system included with Vala (like Robert Rozas mentioned, or via cygwin) to generate executables even without valac installed.

Answer (score 2):

GNOME wiki [recommends](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Vala/ValaOnWindows) using either [MSYS2](http://msys2.org) or [WSL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/wsl/install-win10) (Windows 10 only) to get Vala compiler. Another option is using [ValaForWindows](http://valainstaller.sourceforge.net/), which aims to be the easiest option to install and use.